# if isset check for greater then or eqaul

Tags: php

Hi there I have a successful login and log out system when the user logs in it sets multiple things as follows:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
$_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $USERNAME;
$_SESSION['PASSWORD'] = $PASSWORD;
$_SESSION['AccessLevel'] = $AccessLevel;
```

So what I would like to do, is when I have it check to see if the user is logged in, it also checks if the user is AccessLevel 600 or above and forward them to a new page.

This is what I currently have, any suggestions on how to change it so it may do what I'm looking for would be great. I'm thinking an `els if`, but can't get anything to work.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!(isset($_SESSION['USERNAME']))){
        header("location:../index.html");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is there an actual error? I guess that you should never store a password on a session (why do you do this?) but talk about your design is gonna be too broad.

Comment: more along a santax error but im still learning php so i havent learned if isset much

Comment: ya i will have to talk to the other dev he probably does it for our password change so the way i want it to work is when they log in it redirects them to main page in the header of "main page" it checks to see if they are logged in if so pass to the check of access level if they are below 600 continue if they are above or equal to 600 forward to another page

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!(isset($_SESSION['USERNAME']))){
        echo 'Please Login';
        exit;
    }
    else {
        if ($_SESSION['AccessLevel'] >= 600) {
            echo 'Good User';
            exit;
        }
        else {
            echo 'Access Level is too low';
            exit;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: thank you so much didnt thing you could do els with this statement

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple, hopefully that's what you are looking for. Why not simply check for access level since it is part of the session object.

```
<?php
session_start();

// Check for access level being set in the session object as well as privilege level
if (isset($_SESSION['AccessLevel']) && $_SESSION['AccessLevel'] > 600) {
    header('location: accessible_page.html');
} else {
    header('location: not_logged_in_page.html');
}
?>
```